# figuring out how many block accesses are needed

Tags: sql, oracle, block

Does oracle have a way to figure out how many block accesses are needed for a direct full scan of a particular table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of blocks accessed, is essentially the number of logical/consistent gets your query does. You can use the option `set autotrace traceonly statistics` SQL*Plus to see this statistics value:

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly statistics;
SQL> select * from customers;

115005 rows selected.


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          4  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
       8215  consistent gets
        580  physical reads
          0  redo size
    4689008  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
      84826  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
       7668  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
     115005  rows processed
```

`consistent gets` is the number of blocks the query used (also known as "logical I/O". `physical reads` is the number of blocks actually retrieved from the harddisk (because they were not in the buffer cache).

Answer (score 1):

The total number of I/Os needed to perform a full table scan depends on size of the table(`select blocks from user_segments where segment_name='TABLE_NAME'`), the multi block read count(Controlled by`DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT` parameter), and whether parallel execution is being utilized for the operation.